# Why must one wait for aura phase to end before taking triptan for migraine?

Tags: migraine

All triptan medication instructions tell you to wait for the aura phase to end, and only take the medicine once the pain has started. **What is the reason for this?**

I could not find a **conclusive** answer, as nearly all sources only state the same thing, that you should wait for the aura to end and the pain to begin, **but without giving a reason as to why** (I think it's because they don't know, they only repeat "the old and known *truth*").

[When should triptans be taken during a migraine attack?](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/11524030/) This was the best source for giving at least a minor reason, but even this was somewhat contradictory.

Comment: Interesting. The link you cited pretty strongly suggests there is no reason to wait, and looking at a sample of drug information on drugs.com I saw no mentions of when to take it. If it were important to wait, one would think the manufacturers would say so.